# Is it permissible to remove some of the unuseful code while suggesting an edit?

Tags: discussion, support, suggested-edits

I have suggested an edit on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106941/editview-with-dots). There are two snippets of codes there, which are duplicate and are posted by mistake. I tried to removed one of them and suggested an edit but it got rejected here: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/561934

I would like to know if it is permissible to remove some of the unuseful code, so that I can take care in future suggestions of edits?

---

The same question got edited in the similar fashion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12106941/editview-with-dots#12106941) that I have suggested but by someone else. My edit got rejected. Am I lacking luck?

Comment: That user(after you) has edit question in hurry. so i again edit it with proper meaning.

Comment: @Lucifer Yes..I hope I have suggested correctly but it got rejected.And if you compare the timings, I may be the first one to suggest it so I don't think it could have coincide with others.

Comment: @Haresh: If another user opens the edit page before you submitted your suggestion, but is rather slow with the editing, it is possible to submit a clashing edit, I think.

Comment: @MartijnPieters : if you compare the timing difference of mine and the other person to Suggest the edit,it's exactly 10 mins. And, I would always praise the Service of (Moderators/rep>2000 Users), that they never take more than 5-6 mins to approve/reject the Edit now -a-days..We get result in not more that 5-6 mins.So 10 mins is not a small time.So according to me,the clashing is the least probable thing to happen.

Comment: @Haresh: Yeah, it's most likely the heuristics that rejected your edit. I am talking about theory here; it is theoretically *possible*. :-) In any case, your edit was rejected before the other suggested edit was submitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your suggested edit was rejected automatically, not by human reviewers, that's why it's indicated as rejected by [Community](https://stackoverflow.com/users/-1/community). Suggested edits are automatically rejected if someone else with direct edit rights edits the post. If they start editing after you submit your suggestion, they'll get to review the edit first, but if you were both editing at the same time, the editor who doesn't need approval wins.

The timeline was:

- 09:45:59: user1500635 asks his question
- 09:49:09: you submit your suggested edit
- 09:49:52<sup>†</sup>: user1500635 edits his question (to replace “EditText” with “editview” in the title and remove the `edittext` tag — compare the before part of your [suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/561934/)) with the recorded [revision 1](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12106941/1). Since this edit was made within 5 minutes of the original submission, it is not recorded in the revision history.

Your edit was fine, and should have been approved if humans had reached it. Normally, editing code in questions is not good, so you need to explain carefully why you did it in your edit summary, which you did. Repeated code is a perfectly good reason to delete one of the two code blocks.

<sub><sup>†</sup> I don't think the exact time is shown in the UI but you can get it through the [API](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/posts-on-suggested-edits).</sub>

Comment: @Giles : Thanks for Your Response.And as you suggested that we should explain the edit,I have explain like this way :: "Improved formatting and removed the repeating Code".

Answer (score 3):

In this case, it was certainly the correct edit.

The suggested edit was rejected by Community though, which means it was *automatically* rejected. There probably was another edit on the same post clashed with it (now confirmed as a grace-period edit).

It was not rejected because a reviewer didn't agree with the edit.

Comment: There was a clashing edit, not recorded as such because of the 5-minute window. There are no such rejection heuristics that I know of, and suggested edits that completely remove the text of the post do get through to the queue.

Comment: @Gilles: great! I'll update my post.

Answer (score 1):

Your edit was reviewed by Community. As the Community is an automated process, i think there is no such validation to for checking valid code. But yes it checks for the valid code format. I assume that your suggestion was removed because you removed some part of the code which you thought as useless but Community took it as an **invalid edit**.

However you are correct at your side.

have a look at the following image,

[image]

The original question was like in the image, a code, then a line and again the code. Haresh has remove the upper part of the code but Community reject his suggestion. But the same question was when edit by the other user ( named Shruti ) she removed bottom part of the question ( both were same code spinet ) and this time it was accepted by the Community, i believe that Community is design in such a way for **Approval** and **Rejection**.

For the [direct editing question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges/edit) you require 2K reputation. Users having such or more reputation can edit the post without peer review. This is the reason when the user after you, who did editing, his edit get accepted, because he as 4K reputation.

Comment: But then, after mine,Others also have edited the same by removing the code.And their was accepted.

Comment: no, the other user , and i have more reputation ( > 2K ) so we do not require our edit to be there in review. Whatever we submit it taken as proper edit. When you will have 2K reputation you too have same privilege.

Comment: @Lucifer: Actually, the next edit on that post was from a < 1K user, so that went through the edit queue. See [the second edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12106941/revisions), user has 854 rep.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, agree, but both these user ( Haresh & Shruti ) edited in different pattern. Just check it , Haresh has deleted upper part of the post while Shruti has deleted bottom part of the same code, I think there must be some logic for approval in the Community for this kind of edit.

Comment: And @Lucifer If you will compare the timing of the Suggestions,mine is too before that Shruti have edited.So there is no point in clashing of similar Edit.

Comment: @Lucifer: I agree that it could have been a heuristic trigger, as Haresh removed a bit more than Shruti did, but your statement that the user after the rejected edit is a 2K user is incorrect.

Comment: @Haresh, may be submission clash occurred while hitting the **Enter Key** , moderator or SE developer can more light on it. I answer it based on my observation and experience :)

Comment: @MartijnPieters, when i visited that question it was already edited by some user called nulltoken ( with rep > 4K ), so i mentioned it, that time i was not knowing the this other user called Shruti.